# toggleClass for <p> within one div, where you have more than one div with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide the p's within these divs which have the same class. What I want to happen is when you click the h3, paragraphs show, but only the ones in that div - not all the divs with class "drop"...

```
<div class="drop">
<h3>A heading</h3>
    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
</div><!-- /drop -->


<div class="drop">
<h3>A heading</h3>
    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
</div><!-- /drop -->
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".drop p").addClass('hide');
$(".drop h3").click(function () {
    $(".drop p").toggleClass("show");
    $(".drop h3").toggleClass('goUp');
});
```

classes of 'show' and 'hide' are just display:none and display:block in css. As you can see there could be more than one p in each div.

Any help appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve that like this:

```
$(".drop h3").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('p').slideToggle();
});
```

Like so:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/gjxuH

You could equally use your technique like so:

```
$(".drop h3").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find("p").toggleClass("show");
    $(this).parent().find("h3").toggleClass('goUp');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your click event instead:

```
$(".drop h3").click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll().toggleClass("show");
    $(this).toggleClass('goUp');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/X4nvs/)**

You want to use `this` in the click handler to refer to the element that was clicked on instead of `.drop p` which will select all paragraphs that match that selector.

Comment: Marvelous, thanks! So if there's an image or anything inside that would show/hide too. Great